# Understanding python for loop, with object used as index?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

Here is some test code that I wrote.

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, aty):
        self.number = 0;
        self.anitype = aty;

l = [];
l.append(myclass("tiger"))
l.append(myclass("lion"))
l.append(myclass("puma"))
l.append(myclass("jagur"))

# Method 1 : of course this doesn't work, but I saw a case where it works
#for idx in l: l[idx].number = idx

# Method 2 : of course this works
for idx, lst in enumerate(l):
   l[idx].number = idx

for idx, lst in enumerate(l):
    print("%d : %s" % (lst.number, lst.anitype))
```

The result :

```
0 : tiger
1 : lion
2 : puma
3 : jagur
```

Of course, Method 1 should not work, but today I saw some code that I received from another company and it has a line below.(only the snippets shown)

```
for idx in ls: ls[idx].Oi = idx
```

Here `ls` is a list of class objects. The class has an instance member variable Oi. 
Thinking this line strange, I ran the code with a debugger, and it works! The Oi values of the list member objects are being assigned 0,1,2,3,..

How does this work? By the way, this line of code is seen in a function which is not a member function of a class (it's a global function).

Comment: The data structure for which method 1 works, is a `dict`, not a `list`. When you iterate a `dict`, you iterate its keys. Try it with: `l = {0: 'tiger', 1: 'lion'}`

Comment: Thanks, I found it was a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python there's a mapping type `dict`. When iterating over a dictionary, you're iterating over its keys. To get the values, you still need to use the keys as indices:

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 4}
for key in d:
    print(key, d[key])
```

Output (order may vary):

```
a 3
b 5
c 4
```

It's very likely the code you see is doing this (iterating over a `dict`, or another mapping object, instead of a `list`). If you see something initialized like

```
d = {}  # An empty dict
```

Then it's a `dict` object. (Empty sets are initialized as `set()`)

Comment: Oh, ye, I missed `ls` was initialized by `ls = {}` meaning it is a dict. It's been a while I'm looking at a Python code so I made a mistake.  Now it's clear. Thank!